# How to query the latest version for each app?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table with apps,versions and release dates:

note that it is impossible to have a lower version being release after a newer one. (we would never downgrade versions)

| APP | Ver | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| app1 | 1.2 | 2/17/2022 11:40am |
| app1 | 1.1 | 2/17/2022 11:39am |
| app2 | 1.3 | 2/17/2022 11:38am |
| app3 | 2.6 | 2/17/2022 11:37am |
| app3 | 2.5 | 2/17/2022 11:36am |
| app2 | 1.2 | 2/17/2022 11:35am |

And I want the latest version for each app output:

| APP | Ver | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| app1 | 1.2 | 2/17/2022 11:40am |
| app2 | 1.3 | 2/17/2022 11:38am |
| app3 | 2.6 | 2/17/2022 11:37am |

Im having trouble with the group by, or if there is an easier way Ill be thankful.

Comment: Haven't you tried anything? Like selecting *MAX(date)* per app and then select the rows where app and date match? Or selecting app rows for which *not exists* a newer date? The most typical approach though is using a window function, e.g. `MAX(date) OVER (PARTITION BY app)` and only keep the desired rows. Next time please show your query, so we can comment on it and point you to your mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

`row_number` analytic function will "sort" them by version in descending order; then select those that rank as "highest":

```
with temp as
  (select app, ver, datum,
     row_number() over (partition by app order by datum desc) rn
   from your_table
  )
select app, ver, datum
from temp
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: This only works reliably if version is numeric. Better order by date instead.

Comment: Well, @Thorsten, 1.2 and 2.6 look pretty much *numeric* to me :) But yes, date column is another candidate. Thank you for the comment!

Comment: This is wrong as version numbers are not reliably sortable like this as `1.12 > 1.2` whereas this would sort `1.2 > 1.12`.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the version into the major, minor (and, if it exists, patch) version numbers and order by each of those:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY app
           ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(ver, 1, INSTR(ver, '.') - 1)) DESC,
                    TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(ver, INSTR(ver, '.') + 1)) DESC
         ) AS rn
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Or, using (slower) regular expressions:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY app
           ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(ver, '^(\d+)\.(\d+)$', 1, 1, NULL, 1)) DESC,
                    TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(ver, '^(\d+)\.(\d+)$', 1, 1, NULL, 2)) DESC
         ) AS rn
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (APP, Ver, "DATE") AS
SELECT 'app1', '1.2', CAST(TIMESTAMP '2022-02-17 11:40:00' AS DATE) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'app1', '1.1', CAST(TIMESTAMP '2022-02-17 11:39:00' AS DATE) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'app2', '1.3', CAST(TIMESTAMP '2022-02-17 11:38:00' AS DATE) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'app3', '2.6', CAST(TIMESTAMP '2022-02-17 11:37:00' AS DATE) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'app3', '2.5', CAST(TIMESTAMP '2022-02-17 11:36:00' AS DATE) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'app2', '1.2', CAST(TIMESTAMP '2022-02-17 11:35:00' AS DATE) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'app4', '1.2',  CAST(TIMESTAMP '2022-02-17 11:35:00' AS DATE) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'app4', '1.12', CAST(TIMESTAMP '2022-02-17 11:35:00' AS DATE) FROM DUAL
```

Both output:

> | APP | VER | DATE | RN |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | app1 | 1.2 | 2022-02-17 11:40:00 | 1 |
> | app2 | 1.3 | 2022-02-17 11:38:00 | 1 |
> | app3 | 2.6 | 2022-02-17 11:37:00 | 1 |
> | app4 | 1.12 | 2022-02-17 11:35:00 | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=a59cb47de875cbea4f06d3d4248842db)*

Comment: in your own example, app4 should be 1.2 and your output is 1.12

Comment: @luisluix No, version numbers are not decimals. Version numbers are `<Major>.<Minor>.<Patch>`. So in this case, for `1.12`, the major version number is `1` and the minor version number is `12` and there is no patch version number. For `1.2`, the major version number is `1` and the minor version number is `2` which is less than a minor version of `12`. When you are talking about version numbers, the progression of minor version numbers would go `1.0`, `1.1`, `1.2`, ... `1.9`, `1.10`, `1.11`, `1.12` ... etc. with successively higher minor version numbers that cannot be ordered like decimals.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using `MAX(..) KEEP (DENSE_RANK ..)` analytic function without need of any subquery in order to get the latest per each app group such as

```sql
SELECT app AS "App",
       MAX(ver) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY "date") AS "Ver",
       MAX("date") KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY "date") AS "Date"
  FROM t
 GROUP BY  app
 ORDER BY "App"
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=28528982d6a7114bf12473e8843412c5)</kbd>

*Thanks @MTO for the demo*

Comment: This gets the wrong answer in the demo as version `1.12` is greater than version `1.2` (yes, I deliberately gave them the same timestamp in my demo) and you can also simplify the code using `GROUP BY` and aggregating rather than using `DISTINCT` and analytic functions [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=9b087e4d3f13fe4d7095e805f418478e)

Comment: right, yes, I didn't notice that timestamp value. Thank you @MT0 for the offered case which is cleaner exacly.